# Unit test function calls in constructor in Angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, karma-jasmine

I am working on writing a unit test for the service(refer to code block below) in Angular 2+. How can I achieve this using Jasmine framework ?

```
declare var window: any;

@Injectable
export class Somename {

   constructor() {
     if (window.cordova) {
       function1();
     } else {
       function2();
     }
   }

   private function1() {
   }

   private function2() {
   }
}
```

Comment: Post real code. This code wouldn't compile, and since functions do nothing, there is really nothing to test. Anyway, you can the constructor, and check that it does what it's supposed to do. Whether it delegates to functions doesn't matter.

Comment: Can you update your example code to be more explicit in what the conditions are? We can't see where `condition1` or `condition2` come from.

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel Please check the edited code above. Thank you.

Comment: Do not put business logic in your constructors, it does not belong there. Create methods on your services that are called from components from a defined life cycle event or other event trigger (like UI event). The main reason you are having issue is that the logic does not belong there, on the up side you discovered it while unit testing which is good as unit testing can highlight a poor design choice.

Comment: Gotcha. I will move the code block from constructor to ngOnInit().

Comment: `ngOnInit` will only be called from a Component as it is a life cycle defined on that type. It will never be called indirectly on a service. So if `Somename` is a service that is injected it will have to expose a method that is then called by the component from it's `ngOnInit` method.

Comment: Ok. I need to incorporate that.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could be the skeleton:

```
describe('ComponentExample', () => {
  let component: ComponentExample;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ComponentExample>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ComponentExample ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ComponentExample);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    // Lunch cordova here
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    // Not lunch cordova here 
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

This should works to check constructor, I do not know how to lunch cordova because i did not work with it. But you need to expect component after open or not open the window.

I read some things about ngOnInit, and I think it is not necessary to test the constructor. If you initialize the component you will test the constructor, the problem here is about open cordova. Some way to check if you covered the constructor is using *ng test --code-coverage*. This will generate a directory **coverage** with a *index.html* file that resumes all lines of your code. And says if you covered certain lines or not.

ngOnInit is most using to execute code when you are routting in your application. Is useful if you needs to do something when a component is charged, or a service. But this not differ with this test.

Comment: Hi Jose, Sorry. I hadn't provided enough details earlier. Please refer to the edited block of code above. Thank you.

Comment: @ChetanKhilare I edited the post. I Hope this will help you.